# Extension issue for renamed file for FIle Reading in C / C++

Tags: c, csv, file-io, error-handling, wchar

I have a code for reading the header of a `csv` file. First I check whether the extenson is `.csv` or not. Then I read the file. But the problem is, if I rename any other file, say a `.xml` file or a `.docx` file to `.csv` and then try to read it, then this file extension check doesn't work. It then crashes.
But I want to throw a proper error in such cases. Can anyone help? Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
    // Extracting the extension of the file. Since only csv files are allowed, 
    // for rest of the extensions, appropriate error is being thrown

    sExt = wcsrchr(sFile, L'.');

    if(wcscmp(sExt, L".csv") != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    } 

    _wfopen_s(&fpInpFile, sFile, L"rt");

    if(fpInpFile == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    } 

    while(sChar[lCharIndx] = fgetwc(fpInpFile))
    {
        lVarLength ++;
        lHeaderLength ++;

       // If Variable name is too long, or if the length of the header is too long, throw an error
        if(lVarLength >= 100 || lHeaderLength >= 100)
        {                   
            fclose(fpInpFile);
            return -1;
        }

        // Resetting varibale length before reading length of next variable
        if(sChar[lCharIndx] == ',')
            lVarLength = 0;

        // Header reading is done, so exiting the loop
        if(sChar[lCharIndx] == '\n')
            break;

        lCharIndx ++;
    }

    fclose(fpInpFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(sChar[lCharIndx] = fgetwc(fpInpFile))
```

You should't check for end-of-file this way. Instead:

```
wint_t wch;
while ((wch = fgetwc(fpInpFile)) != WEOF)
{
    sChar[lCharIndx] = wch;
```

Also, you should check whether `lCharIndx` is within array size of `sChar` or not.

Comment: yah. you are correct. I forgot the end of file check completely. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Regarding lCharIndx, it's not an issue as the check lHeaderLength >= 100 ensures that lCharIndx is always within array size of sChar (which is 100). But it does not address my original issue, that of the extension of an edited file. Can you please help me out on that too? Thanks again.

Comment: @sudiptaasi You should identify and throw the error when you find you cannot support the file format